# Django import-export: Export a many-to-many relationship as though it was the base model

Tags: django, django-import-export

### What I have

Two models, `User`s and `Magazine`s, in a many-to-many relationship via a `Subscription`s table. The rough model structure is:

```
class User(models.Model):
    # ...

class Magazine(models.Model):
    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Subscription")
    # ...

class Subscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, ...
    magazine = models.ForeignKey(Magazine, ...
    signed_up_on = models.DateField()
    active = models.BooleanField()
```

### What I want

Magazines have their own admin, but subscriptions don't. They're displayed as an inline in each magazine's detail view. I need to export the *subscriptions*, but not the magazines, via a button (or admin action) on the *magazine* admin page.

All I need in the returned data are the user and magazine ids, as well as the other columns on the subscription table.

I tried hacking this together via the options I found in the django import-export docs, but couldn't figure out a way to do this. Overriding subscription resource's `get_queryset()` method didn't do anything because that method is only called when the queryset is `None`, and the library helpfully populates the queryset ahead of time.

The `ManyToManyWidget` also looked promising, but it concatenates every associated value into the same cell. I don't need one row per magazine with all subscriptions concatenated together, I need one row per subscription.

Is there a way to do this without implementing my own admin actions?